# excel function that can take a number such as 4 and return 4/1/2020 and also the last day

Tags: excel

I need the function to look at a cell that holds a month. They are different months in each cell.

Example:

4

I need a function that looks at this number, and returns 4/1/2020. I also need one that returns the end of the month. So 4/30/2020.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the first day of the month:

```
=DATE(2020,A1,1)
```

for the last day of the month:

```
=DATE(2020,A1+1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE():

```
=DATE(2020,A1,1)
```

And EOMONTH():

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(2020,A1,1),0)
```

[image]